# How to parse JSON with jQuery while ignoring first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data in this format:

```
    {
   "status":"Good",
   "open_slots":[
      {
         "date":"Tue, Jun 28, 2016",
         "time_slot":"9:15 AM"
      },
      {
         "date":"Tue, Jun 28, 2016",
         "time_slot":"12:30 PM"
      },
      {
         "date":"Tue, Jun 28, 2016",
         "time_slot":"2:00 PM"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I ignore the 'status' portion of the data and build a list based on open_slots with jQuery?

Comment: What about just `jsonData.open_slots`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json = JSON.parse(input);
var json_keep = json.open_slots;
```

Now you can loop over just the open slots:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_keep.length; i++) {
    alert("Found date/time_slot: " + json_keep[i].date + "/" + json_keep[i].time_slot);
}
```